# How to introduce simplest cross browser bug in angular 9 application?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, cross-browser, polyfills

Recently I get to know about [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) that it reduces incompatibility among browsers and that has got added to my fresh angular project which I generated using angular-cli using `ng new my-app`.

In my case, I want to introduce a simple bug which is due to browser incapability. How can I do that without creating other side effects in angular 9 app?

Comment: Go to Es6 polyfill repo and pick through methods and look up browser compatibility for the methods in MDN docs. Then use a method in a browser that doesn't support it...probably in IE

Answer (score 0):

I added simplest cross browser bug by adding `input` tag of type `datetime-local` in template part of component.

```
<input type="datetime-local" formControlName="startTime" class="form-control" id="startTime" placeholder="Start Time">
```

On firefox this will be rendered as
[image]

On firefox this will be rendered as
[image]

On two browser look is different so its a cross browser bug.